# Changing order of integration in infinite-dimensional space

Tags: functional-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Assume you have a probability distribution $F$ over density functions $g$. Under what circumstances (if ever), is it possible to change the order of integration for the double integral $\int \int m g(m) dm dF(g)$, i.e. when is

\begin{equation}
\int \int m g(m) dm dF(g) = \int m \int g(m)dF(g)dm
\end{equation}

Essentially, I think I am looking for something like Fubini's theorem for infinite-dimensional spaces. I would be grateful on any advice for a functional analysis book where to read up on this problem or ideally some theorem pertinent to the above question. In my application, I can assume that $F$ and $g$ are arbitrarily well-behaved, so even a quite restrictive statement would be sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Typical formulations of Fubini just assume $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and the integrand has to be measurable w.r.t. the product $\sigma$-algebra. This should be enough for your purpose?

Comment: Can I assume that a $\sigma$-finite measure exists? I guess me assuming that there is a probability distribution F implies that a $\sigma$-finite measure must exist otherwise it makes no sense to talk about F and I also see no good reason apart from this why such a measure would not exist,  but given my limited/non-existent knowledge of functional analysis, I guess I would just like to confirm that I don't run into any weird issues when discussing measures over function spaces.

Comment: Since $F$ is a probability distribution, it generates a finite measure (which is, automatically, $\sigma$-finite). If I guess correctly, the integral denoted by $\mathrm d m$ is over real numbers w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Again, this measure is $\sigma$-finite. So you only have to check the measurability of the integrand, in particular of $(m,g) \mapsto g(m)$. This depends crucially on your $\sigma$-algebra over the density functions.

Comment: @user5211657 did you find a satisfactory resolution of this question? I am faced with the same question in my work. Could you please point to any relevant material you may have found while researching this? Thanks

Comment: Someone read this book and tell me if it answers the question: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0083099